# getting compilation error for ajaxbehaviour event while using it in bean class listener method

Tags: ajax

I used ajax listener attribute  in xhtml page.
  while using ajax behaviourevent  in  listener method in bean class, i am getting compilation error.

public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event).

} 
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved by adding  `javax.faces-api-2.1.jar`.

Thanks